# Finding if a Queue has more elements

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have the following code. I m trying to access a queue and consume resources, well i dont know how many elements are in the queue and how many left, so i am doing `while(true)` but in this case, i cant close the connection which causes errors, later on, like the process doesnt die. even though i stopped it.

How can i find if there are more items in the queue then do the following ? i looked at ActiveMqQueueBrowser but it s internal so i cant really use it easily.

What would you do? What do u recommend?

```
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    while(true){
            Message message = consumer.receive();

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                System.out.println("message from queue : '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
            }
    }

   // unreachable code. compiler complains.
   // connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have another thread.  How do you know when to be done listening?  If its where the consumerQueue no longer has a value, try this:

```
while(true){
        Message message = consumer.receive(//some int timeout);
        if (message == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("message from queue : '" + textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }
}
```

Otherwise you are right, the loop will never return and you won;t be able to close the connections correctly when the JVM comes down.

Answer (score 0):

Well how long do you want to wait for more messages to arrive? Unless there's any guarantee that no more messages can come in, you can't really say when it's "done".

You can give a timeout to `receive()` or call `receiveNoWait()` and break if the return value is `null`, meaning there was no message available in the given time period.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a couple of options for determining what is available on a given destination in ActiveMQ.  The broker exposes a great deal of information of JMX so if you are comfortable with that you can connect and get the number of Messages that are enqueued.  Another option that doesn't involve using JMX is to use the Broker Statistics plugin.  This plugin allows you to send a message to the broker with a ReplyTo destination set and it will respond with a Message containing the current statistics of the Destination.  See the documentation for the statistics plugin [here](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html).